# getClipboard broken after setClipboard

Tags: java, clipboard

So, I have a loop for checking for any changes in the system clipboard, during this loop, a user can request that sets the clipboard. However, after setting the clipboard, anything that is copied in the system is not picked up by `getClipboard`, while pasting into any text editor will display any text you've just copied.

Here's the code I've been using to test:

```
public final class TextTransfer implements ClipboardOwner {

    public static void main(String...  aArguments ) throws InterruptedException {
        TextTransfer textTransfer = new TextTransfer();

        //display what is currently on the clipboard
        System.out.println("Clipboard contains:" + textTransfer.getClipboardContents());

        //change the contents and then re-display
        textTransfer.setClipboardContents("blah, blah, blah");
        System.out.println("Clipboard contains:" + textTransfer.getClipboardContents());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Clipboard contains:" + textTransfer.getClipboardContents());
    }
    /**
    * Empty implementation of the ClipboardOwner interface.
    */
    @Override public void lostOwnership(Clipboard aClipboard, Transferable aContents){
        //do nothing
    }

    /**
    * Place a String on the clipboard, and make this class the
    * owner of the Clipboard's contents.
    */
    public void setClipboardContents(String aString){
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(aString);
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, this);
    }

    /**
    * Get the String residing on the clipboard.
    *
    * @return any text found on the Clipboard; if none found, return an
    * empty String.
    */
    public String getClipboardContents() {
        String result = "";
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        //odd: the Object param of getContents is not currently used
        Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
        boolean hasTransferableText =
            (contents != null) &&
                    contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)
            ;
        if (hasTransferableText) {
            try {
                result = (String)contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            }
            catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex){
                System.out.println(ex);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
     }
}
```

So, I was wondering if anyone else had the same issue, I am using a Mac OS, using Java 1.7!